# Core Data Inheritance - Manage Inverse relationships of subclasses

Tags: swift, database, core-data, polymorphism, relationship

I am new to CoreData environment and I'm trying to understand how it works.
In my project, I have a superclass `VetExam` whose subclasses are `Examination`, `Treatments` and `Vaccination`, which share the same attributes of their superclass and has a reference to `Pet` class. On the other hand, `Pet` class holds an array of reference of every class except of `VetExam`, which should only be used for Polymorphism (so that I can use `VetExam` object and create a single view for each type).

Based on this model, I've tried to create entities in CoreData, but it seems that I have to specify for each type the inverse relationship for each entity. This represent a problem since from `VetExam` entity side the relationship is of type `Pet` but on `Pet` side is To-Many for each type of Examination, which does not allow me to get the inverse reference of `VetExam`.

Since this explaination can easily be misunderstood, I will show you the visual representation of it.

[image: what should I put in inverse??]
[image: no vetexam]

The problem is in `VetExam` entity, whose Inverse attribute is not known.
Does anyone know how to deal with this type of situation?

Comment: Either don't have a relationship from VetExam to Pet but instead relationships from the subclasses to Pet or have only one to-many relationship in Pet to VetExam or maybe give up using inheritance here and let Examination, Treatment and Vaccination be 3 indenpendent entities. The last option might be the easiest in the long run even if you have to duplicate some properties.

Comment: Giving up inheritance would mean to change app structure, since it does not rely on core data atm

Answer (score 1):

A preliminary note on inheritance...

[Class inheritance](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Inheritance.html)

AND

[Entity inheritance](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/KeyConcepts.html)

For the second, I highlight the note in the Apple Documentation:

> Be careful with entity inheritance when working with SQLite persistent
>   stores. All entities that inherit from another entity exist within the
>   same table in SQLite. This factor in the design of the SQLite
>   persistent store can create a performance issue.

What this means is that Core Data framework creates one large table in the SQLite database that includes the parent entity and the child entities. Such a large table inherently contains inefficiencies. While this may seem convenient for you to manage now in your model editor and in your NSManagedObject subclasses, this may cause inefficiencies / performance issues in the long run if you expect your app to persist and retrieve large amounts of data in the four entities you mention.

Advice from others is very relevant here because four separate entities will in my humble opinion be easier to manage, rather than one parent entity and three child entities. You do not have to give up the class inheritance you’ve developed in your code if you choose this option.

**So, to answer your question...**

My logic:

Every Pet may have many instances of VetExam during its life, but each instance of VetExam is carried out on only one Pet?

If yes, then create a one-to-many relationship between Pet and VetExam -

```
 Pet <—>> VetExam.
```

Whatever occurs during the VetExam is any combination of one Examination, Treatment and/or Vaccination. That is and in an attempt to be clear, the VetExam may optionally have an examination, but it may not have a treatment or a vaccination. This is likely to change for each VetExam, therefore this is directly related to the VetExam, not the Pet.

If yes, then create optional one-to-one relationships between VetExam and the entities Examination, Treatment and Vaccination.

```
 VetExam <—> Examination
 VetExam <—> Treatment
 VetExam <—> Vaccination
```

In this model, each entity relationship detailed above has an inverse.

Finally, it might be worth noting that in this proposed model, the relationship between a Pet and all the examinations, treatments and vaccinations it receives during its lifetime is stored against PetExam, not directly against the Pet.